# Improving the curve of a quadratic spline interpolation

Tags: plotting, fitting, interpolation, piecewise

I have these data and I want to make a curve using quadratic spline interpolation. I am successful in computing the equations and plotting the curves. However, I noticed that the peaks of the curves at tail end of the plot are so great. Is there a way to minimize them maybe something close to the plot when using Mathematica's built-in Interpolation function with InterpolationOrder->2?

```
    dataPoints ={{0.00265735, 3.03692}, {0.00531471, 3.04674}, {0.00797206, 3.06328}, {0.0106294, 3.08672}, {0.0132868, 3.11723}, {0.0159441, 3.15497}, {0.0186015, 3.20015}, {0.0212588, 3.25295}, {0.0239162, 3.31358}, {0.0265735, 3.38224}, {0.0531471, 4.55737}, {0.0797206, 6.73052}, {0.106294, 9.83647}, {0.132868, 13.5431}, {0.159441, 17.4688}, {0.186015, 20.5589}, {0.212588, 21.4072}, {0.239162, 20.0896}, {0.265735, 17.8266}, {0.531471, 7.96131}, {0.797206, 5.05786}, {1.06294, 3.67306}, {1.32868, 2.86511}, {1.59441, 2.3415}, {1.86015, 1.97695}, {2.12588, 1.70889}, {2.39162, 1.50349}, {2.65735, 1.34124}};
    
    Length[dataPoints];
    (*number of splines*)
    n = Length[dataPoints] - 1;
    
    (*Compute the quadratic spline coefficients*)
    splineCoeffs = Table[{a[i], b[i], c[i]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

Using the quadratic spline conditions to solve for the coefficients:

```
        (*all points *)
        f1 = Table[dataPoints[[i,2]] == a[i]*dataPoints[[i,1]]^2 + b[i]*dataPoints[[i,1]] + c[i], {i,1,n}];
        f2 = Table[dataPoints[[i+1,2]] == a[i]*dataPoints[[i+1,1]]^2 + b[i]*dataPoints[[i+1,1]] + c[i],{i,1,n}];
        
        (*interior(common) data points*)
        f3 = Table[2*a[i]*dataPoints[[i+1,1]] + b[i] == 2*a[i+1]*dataPoints[[i+1,1]] + b[i+1],{i,1, n-1}];
        
        (*initial condition*)
        a[1] = 0;
        
        eqs = Flatten[{f1, f2, f3}];
        coeff = Solve[eqs, Drop[Flatten[splineCoeffs],1]];
```

Plotting the curves:

```
            (*first linear equation*)
            f = coeff[[1,1,2]]*x + coeff[[1,2,2]]
            
            (*parabolic equations*)
            g = Table[coeff[[1,i,2]]*x^2 + coeff[[1,i+1,2]]*x + coeff[[1,i+2,2]],{i,3,3*n-3,3}]
            
            spline[x_] := Piecewise[Table[{g[[i]],dataPoints[[i+1,1]]<x<dataPoints[[i+2,1]]},{i,1,n-1}]]
            
            Show[ListPlot[dataPoints, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], Plot[f,{x,dataPoints[[1,1]], dataPoints[[2,1]]},PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[spline[x],{x,dataPoints[[2,1]],dataPoints[[-1,1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Comment: The figure (I added hopefully correctly) shows overfitting.  Is that the issue about which you're concerned?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it is. Though it fits the conditions for a quadratic spline interpolation, the generated tail of the plot is not "correct". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mule The condition `a[1]==0` is arbitrary. There might be an optimal choice of `a[1]` with smoother interpolation.